# Plotting mean and sd of density for one year as a bar graph in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart, mean, standard-deviation

I am trying to create a bar graph in R that will show the mean density at year 20 for different sizes of a density reduction area (1, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25 square miles) at different harvest rates (30%, 35%, 40%, 45%, 50%). Below is an example of my data (called "deerharvest"):

```
    total.sink.density    size    year   harvest.rate
    26.4                  1       1      0.30
    25.7                  1       1      0.35
    22.9                  1       1      0.40
    20.1                  1       1      0.45
    18.7                  1       1      0.50
     .                    .       .        .
     .                    .       .        .
     .                    .       .        .
    6.5                   25      20     0.30
    7.2                   25      20     0.35
    6.9                   25      20     0.40
    6.5                   25      20     0.45
    7.0                   25      20     0.50
```

Using the code found online for "summarySE" I can get some descriptive statistics (mean, sd, se and ci):

```
 newdeerharvest <- summarySE(deerharvest, 
 measurevar="total.sink.density", groupvars=c("harvest.rate","size"))
```

I think ggplot would accomplish what I want to do. I've tried playing around with this code:

```
ggplot(newdeerharvest, aes(x=size, y=total.sink.density, fill=harvest.rate)) + 
geom_bar(position=position_dodge(), stat="identity") +
geom_errorbar(aes(ymin=total.sink.density-sd, ymax=total.sink.density+sd)
```

However, this will provide means over all 20 years. I would want to plot the means of just year 20, for each size and harvest rate. Is there any way to accomplish this without subsetting the data first? I would need to make this same graph for multiple datasets. Any insight is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your code isn't reproducible, since `sd` is not a variable in the data you posted. If you only want to use 1 year, you will have to subset.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I missed that. I edited my question to be more clear. But if I have to subset regardless, then thank you for your response.